# Overlapping content with Parallax Scroll effect

Tags: scroll, parallax, effect

**About:**

- Finished a very basic Parallax Scrolling effect tutorial with jQuery. The effect works as it should.

**My issue:**

- Content allready overlaps the background image when first viewing the page by a certain amount of pixels. This needs to start right below the viewport (and thus, background image).

**My question:** What exactly do I need to change (or add) in order to make it start below the background image?

**My attempts to resolve:**

- Tried setting a fixed height of 100% to the background in order to have the content part start out of sight (below the background image). This removed my background as a whole and pushed the content further upwards.
- Tried changing .content height from 1500px to lower or higher. This is not ideal, unfortunately.
- Tried changing .parallax-bg padding from 300px to higher in order to push the content down. It works, but I am not certain wether this works on different resolutions.

**My coding:**

```js
(function() {
    var documentEl = $(document),
        parallaxBg = $('div.parallax-bg');
 
    documentEl.on('scroll', function() {
     var currScrollPos = documentEl.scrollTop();
     parallaxBg.css('background-position', '0 ' + -currScrollPos/4 + 'px');
    });
})();
```

```css
html, body  {
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 padding:0;
 margin:0;
}

.content {
 height:1500px;
 background-color:#333;
}

.parallax-bg {
 padding:300px 0;
 background-image:url('/img/bg.png');
 background-size:cover;
 background-attachment:fixed;
 -webkit-transition:all 0.2s ease;
 -moz-transition:all 0.2s ease;
 transition:all 0.2s ease;
}

.parallax-bg h1 {
 text-align:center;
 text-transform:uppercase;
 color:#fff;
 font-size:70px;
 font-family:arial:
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
 <html>
  <head>
   <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
   <div class="content">
    <div class="parallax-bg">
     <h1>Hello Everybody</h1>
    </div>
   </div>

   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/scrolling.js"></script>
  </body>
 </html>
```